# Most efficient way of selecting a set of elements

Tags: jquery, css

Example, if I have an unordered list lets say,

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Foo</li>
    <li class="bar">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

I can select foo as `$('ul li.foo')`, `$('li.foo')` or `$('.foo')`.

Then which way is more efficient (if any) and why. Or is it that specifying parents while selecting children is only for the sole reason to remove any conflict in case there are other elements having same class name!

Comment: Depends on the OS/browser/version involved, and which jQuery version. Which one(s) do you care about? Further, this smells like [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) at its finest.

Comment: Its better to select element using ID, in your case you can add ID for UL. Otherwise there is chance of multiple elements with same class and hierarchy.

Comment: @Phrogz This came just out of curiosity. Plus you mentioned it depends on the OS/browser/version. Can you elaborate little more!

Comment: @srijan Some older browsers do not have support for `getElementsByClassName`, for example, and so the benefits of a native lookup there would be lost; if these browsers have, however, `getElementsByTagName` then selecting by tag first and then paring down by class may be faster than selecting all elements and then paring down (untested). For example: see the **IE7 and IE8 results** in the performance test page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple class selector `.foo` will be fastest in modern browsers, because it can use the native [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) where available.

Here's a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jq-selector-comparisons) showing exactly that:

[image]

You can run that performance test in all the browsers that matter to you, and make a decision based on the results. Or just use the selector that works best for your situation, since in the real world it's going to make no noticeable difference whatsoever.

**Update**

Now that we can see the performance results from a wider selection of browsers, you can see the difference between old and new (lack of `getElementsByClassName` in IE7 and 8). However, you are likely these days to receive significantly more traffic from newer browsers, but I don't know your site, so as I mentioned previously, you just need to pick what works for you. If for whatever reason 90% of your traffic comes from IE7, you should probably use `li.foo`.

Comment: This is great. By intuition I thought the same as there will be lesser overhead to track down the elements. Thanks for the elaboration. That was really helpful.

Comment: @srijan - No problem, glad I could help :) http://jsperf.com is a great tool any time you have a question about the performance of various JavaScript snippets.

Answer (score 3):

`.foo` is the fastest selector in modern browsers.  The other selectors will select `.foo`, then filter out anything which isn't an `li` then (for `$('ul li.doo')`) iterate up through the tree and make sure there is a `ul` somewhere.

However `.foo` will not be the fastest in older browsers without [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll). Such as IE 6.

The fastest by a long shot would be to use an id and do `$('#foo')` if you know you will only have one `foo` on the page.

[Here is a benchmark](http://jsperf.com/selectory-selectorisms)